# How to compute the probability that X is within 1 standard deviation of its mean for pareto?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

A random variable X is Pareto( α, β ). Compute the probability that X is
   within 1 standard deviation of its mean.

I'm not sure how to do this without specified values...

I have this information:[pareto info][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQfJX.png. This lists the parameters, then the mean, and the variance. I also know the Standard deviation is the square root of the variance. I'm a little stuck, can you give me some hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use your stated choice of parameters $\alpha, \beta$ and the parametrization that yields the expectation and variance shown in the attached image, namely $$X \sim \operatorname{Pareto}(\alpha,\beta) \iff f_X(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{\beta \alpha^\beta}{x^{\beta + 1}}, & x \ge \alpha \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}, \end{cases}$$ hence $$\mu = \operatorname{E}[X] = \begin{cases} \frac{\alpha\beta}{\beta-1}, & \beta > 1 \\ \text{undefined}, & \text{otherwise},\end{cases} \quad \sigma^2 = \operatorname{Var}[X] = \begin{cases} \frac{\alpha^2 \beta}{(\beta - 1)^2 (\beta-2)}, & \beta > 2 \\ \text{undefined}, & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases} $$
Furthermore, the Pareto CDF is given by $$\Pr[X \le x] = F_X(x) = \begin{cases} 0, & x < \alpha \\ 1 - (\alpha/x)^\beta, & x \ge \alpha. \end{cases}$$
  Thus, one standard deviation within the mean is the interval $[\max(\alpha, \mu - \sigma), \mu + \sigma]$.  This is because we must take care to consider the case when $\mu - \sigma < \alpha$, for if this occurs, the lower endpoint of this interval must be taken as $\alpha$ as $X$ has support on $[\alpha,\infty)$.

To this end, we solve the equality $$\sigma^2 = (\mu - \alpha)^2,$$ or equivalently, $$\frac{\alpha^2 \beta}{(\beta-1)^2 (\beta-2)} = \left(\frac{\alpha \beta}{\beta - 1} - \alpha\right)^2.$$  A straightforward cancellation gives $\beta/(\beta-2) = 1$, which is of course impossible, so equality never occurs.  But which direction is the inequality?  The direction must be the same for any legitimate choice of parameters, so we can choose for example $\alpha = 2$ and $\beta = 3$, giving $\mu = 3 = \sigma^2 = 3$, hence we always have $\mu-\sigma > \alpha$ and we need not worry about the lower endpoint.  It follows that the desired probability is simply $$\Pr[|X-\mu| \le \sigma] = F_X(\mu+\sigma) - F_X(\mu-\sigma) = \left(\frac{\alpha}{\mu-\sigma}\right)^\beta - \left(\frac{\alpha}{\mu+\sigma}\right)^\beta.$$  Simplifying this gives $$\Pr[|X-\mu| \le \sigma] = \left(\frac{\beta - 1}{\beta - \sqrt{\beta/(\beta-2)}}\right)^\beta - \left(\frac{\beta - 1}{\beta + \sqrt{\beta/(\beta-2)}}\right)^\beta.$$  Note this expression is independent of $\alpha$.

Comment: thank you! I have a much clearer idea of how to approach these kinds of questions now!